# mysql server quit without updating pid file on centos

Tags: linux, mysql, centos

I am not able to start MySQL , i am gettting this error

```
[root@server scripts]# service mysql start
Starting MySQL.The server quit without updating PID file (/[FAILED]mysql/server.mydomain.com.pid).
```

what should i do

I dont have any `my.cnf` file anywhere

only have these

```
/etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf
/home/monty/.mylogin.cnf
/opt/rightscale/sandbox/openssl.cnf
/root/.mylogin.cnf
/usr/share/doc/MySQL-server-5.6.10/my-default.cnf
/usr/share/mysql/my-default.cnf
/var/lib/mysql/auto.cnf
```

Comment: what error you are getting in mysql error log tail 100f /var/log/mysqld.log ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CentOS you need to copy `/usr/share/doc/MySQL-server-5.6.10/my-default.cnf` to `/etc/my.cnf` and you have to make changes in my.cnf as per your server configuration,after every changes in my.cnf to get reflect you need to restart you mysql server.

It seems you have issue with you permission on mysql datadir. Run below command

```
mysql_install_db
```

This command will check your mysql configuration and find out the errors . Once this is done

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /path to your mysql data dir ( default is /var/lib/mysql)

brew service mysql restart
```

Comment: I had the error that my `/tmp` permission gets changed , i have made that 777 an dnow that worked. Can i still now do that `mysql_install_db`. because i think i am currently using default conf file

Comment: if mysql is working for you and you are not in mood to play around it with than you can leave it.

Comment: But i want to chnage the default config and want that so that mysql should write pid in different folder not in /tmp folder

Comment: So copy /usr/share/doc/MySQL-server-5.6.10/my-default.cnf to /etc as my.cnf and define your own custom paramaters for mysql .

Comment: i checked from here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-default-changes.html but could not find `pid_file` parameter there.

Comment: pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid like this in my.cnf you can define and give restart to mysql make sure mysql user have enough permissions on /var/run/mysqld directory.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue on CentOS 6. Abhishek Anand Amralkar has a good suggestion because the `/etc/my.cnf` installed by CentOS on my system (due to mysql-libs as an dependency package installed by anaconda) had the following:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

The `pid-file` parameter was referencing a directory and file that did not exist on my system and even if it did, the `mysql:mysql` user:group needs to be granted permissions to edit it.

So the bottom-line is make sure you know where your *real* `my.cnf` file is (`cd / ; nice find . -name "my.cnf"`), that it is the actual one that mysql is using when it runs, and that it has the correct configuration for the installation you created. I think a lot of CentOS users are getting tripped up by this default `my.cnf` in `/etc`.

A quick solution is to simply:

```
mv /etc/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf.old
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the current suggestions fail. Make sure that /var/lib has a 775 permission.